# How to get a working document preview link from MS Graph

Tags: rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to get a preview link for the useres recent documents over MS Graph. Unfortunately the link the endpoint returns does not work.

To get the informations about a file I first call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/recent`. Then I copy the driveID and the id of a document from the parentReference property.

To get the preview link I use the Endpoint `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/<DriveID>/items/<DocumentID>/preview`
and this works fine. But when I click on the link I get the error "This item might not exist or is no longer avaiable". The document exists on the SharePoint, otherwise it would not appear under "recent documents". The url looks like this: `https://www.onedrive.com/embed?webUrl=xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/nameOfTheSite/docLibName&id=sites/nameOfTheSite/DocLibName&embed=xxx&authToken=xxx`

I expect the response of the `/preview` endpoint should return a working url. Do I have to make some configurations on O365?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed link (`preview`) does not look *valid* in your example since `id` parameter refers to **container** (library): `sites/nameOfTheSite/DocLibName`. It is not supported, instead embed link should refer to a **file**

Most likely the issue is due to `itemId`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/<DriveID>/items/<DocumentID>/preview
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in your example it seems refers to a library instead of a file. Make sure the proper `itemId` is specified.

For example, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent` endpoint returns the following payload:

```
{
   "value" : {
       //another properties are omitted for a clarity
       //... 
       "remoteItem": {
           "id": "01ECKZLCWSR7F76B64KZFL7I3QGZVPJELU"
           //...   
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "b!79yKq-2MdkSDnQ7_1Pf3FOkRyDCajpRIvqtA7UrsEO-vu3D_qkpaT50Y6CMcSmFv",
                "driveType": "documentLibrary",
                "id": "01ECKZLCV6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
            },
       }
   }
}
```

where

- `remoteItem.Id`  -  corresponds to item id for a file
- `remoteItem.parentReference.driveId` - corresponds to drive id

> Dont get confused with `remoteItem.parentReference.Id` which corresponds
>   to item id of library